# Microsoft's ServiceProvider class needs reassigning, otherwise returns null?

Tags: c#, .net

I started by creating the instances I needed.

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then I passed them into the method that required them.

```
RegisterDependencies(serviceCollection, serviceProvider);
```

Here is that method.

```
private static void RegisterDependencies(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // removed lines to make it minimal...

    var coreContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ICoreContext>();

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConnectionHandler, ConnectionHandler>(provider =>
        new ConnectionHandler(coreContext, IPAddress.Any, 300)
    );

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<INetworkHandler, NetworkHandler>(provider =>
        new NetworkHandler(serviceProvider.GetService<IConnectionHandler>())
    );
}
```

Now, everything works fine until we have to call `GetService` on the ServiceProvider class, like this

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IConsoleCommandHandler>()
```

The `GetService` method will return null, unless its reassigned, like this.

```
serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Is there a work around, or a better way of doing it, is this even natural behavior for it? What if I call GetService 20 times after the instance has been made, I have to reassign it 20 times?

To further explain the problem, I've shown an example below.

this will work

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICoreContext, CoreContext>(provider =>
    new CoreContext(
        serviceProvider.GetService<IConsoleCommandHandler>(),
        new PacketProvider(new Dictionary<short, IAsyncPacket>())
    )
);

serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var coreContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ICoreContext>();
```

This wont work.

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICoreContext, CoreContext>(provider =>
    new CoreContext(
        serviceProvider.GetService<IConsoleCommandHandler>(),
        new PacketProvider(new Dictionary<short, IAsyncPacket>())
    )
);

// serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var coreContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ICoreContext>();
```